# I had an error when i am creating a foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created three tables as products, categories, and subcategories. To create a relationship within them I used foreign keys. How can I sort it out?

sub_categories - Table

```
    Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('id');
                $table->string('cat_id');
                $table->timestamps();
    
                $table->string('cat_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            });
```

categories - Table

```
     Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('id');
                $table->string('cat_name');
                $table->string('cat_image_path')->nullable();
                $table->string('cat_description')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

products - Table

```
     Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('id');
                $table->string('prod_name');
                $table->string('prod_brand')->nullable();
                $table->string('cat_id');
                $table->string('prod_description')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_item_code')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_modal')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_size')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_weight')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_height')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_manufacturer')->nullable();
                $table->float('prod_price')->nullable();
                $table->float('prod_discount')->nullable();
                $table->float('prod_quantity')->nullable();
                $table->string('prod_image_path')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
    
                $table->foreign('cat_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            });
```

This is the error which I got,

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'cat_id' (SQL: create table `sub_categories` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `cat_id` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `cat_id` varchar(255) not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:129
      Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'cat_id'")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:127
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'cat_id'")
```

Can anyone please give a hand to sort out this?

Comment: use `$table->id();` instead of `$table->string('id')` and `$table->unsignedBigInteger('cat_id');` instead of `$table->string('cat_id')` in your migrations

Comment: There are a lot mistake, `$table->string('id');` should be `$table->bigIncreaments('id');` and all your foreign id should be `unsingnedBigInteger` like `$table->unsignedBigInteger('cat_id');` and your `categories` table should be migrate before `sub_categories` and your migrate will be `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `id` in every table is of type `string`.

`id` must be of type `unsignedBigInteger`. You can achieve this by either writing `$table->id()`, `$table->bigIncrements('id');`or `$table->unsignedBigInteger('id')`

Your foreign key fields like `cat_id` etc. also can't be of type `string`. They must have the same type as written above.

Please take a look into the official documenttion about this. I am sure this will help you.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score -1):

When creating the "sub_categories" table, you are repeating the creation of the "cat_id" field. I think you should try the following in the "sub_categories" table:

```
Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->string('cat_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```